# Yandex Spellchecker отказывается работать на сильно исковерканном тексте

Tags: python, текст, обработка-ошибок, работа-с-текстом, классификация-текста

Я пытаюсь привести в нормальную форму тексты постов из соцмедиа. При помощи Polyglot определяю язык и затем привожу текст в форму при помощи YandexSpellChecker. Проблема в том, что Polyglot часто ложно определяет как белорусский (или другие языки на кириллице) некоторые тексты на русском, видимо они содержат какие-то ошибки или специфические элементы. Использование других методов определения языка дает результат не лучше.

Я пытаюсь обойти это затруднение, применяя YandexSpellChecker, чтобы удалить из русского текста ошибки и улучшить процент выявления языка. К сожалению, при наличии большого количества ошибок YandexSpellChecker отказывается работать. Я тестировала его на небольших датафреймах, где он работает безупречно. Но стоит ему получить какую-либо очень исковерканную строчку, я получаю ответ IndexError: list index out of range. То же самое на отдельных строчках - то результат норм, то полный отказ.

Мне хотелось бы, чтобы в случае таких сложных строчек, где определение невозможно, YandexSpellChecker выдавал бы результат в виде текста "error" и продолжал анализировать строчки дальше. Такой результат был бы идеальным, так как тогда я бы смогла распознать текст, написанный на белорусском (или другом языке) и далее обращалась бы с ним как с белорусским.

Может кто помочь?

Мой код для строки:

```
from pyaspeller import YandexSpeller
speller = YandexSpeller()
text = 'Што яшчэ адзин мышибратья выляз ВЯРТАЙЦЕ'
changes = {change['word']: change['s'][0] for change in speller.spell(text)}
for word, suggestion in changes.items():
    text = text.replace(word, suggestion)
text
```

Для датафрейма:

```
def spellcheck(text):
    speller = YandexSpeller()
    changes = {change['word']: change['s'][0] for change in speller.spell(text)}
    for word, suggestion in changes.items():
            text = text.replace(word, suggestion)
    return text  

df_kyr['text2']= df_kyr['tidy_text'].apply(spellcheck)
df_kyr
```

Comment: а почему не оформить логику в функции `spellcheck()` в `try: ... except ...` блок ?

Comment: @MaxUСпасибо. Да, это мне и нужно, но сделать это правильно мне как новичку сложно. Когда я выполняю: def spellcheck(text):
    speller = YandexSpeller()
    changes = {change['word']: change['s'][0] for change in speller.spell(text)}
    try:
        for word, suggestion in changes.items():
            text = text.replace(word, suggestion)
        return text
    except Exception as error:
            print (error) и применяю ее к колонкам  df, получаю все ту же ошибку. Мне нужно, чтобы функция писала сообщение об ошибке и продолжала обрабатывать следующую ячейку. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Ок, как предложил @MaxU, сработал try... except... в таком виде:

```
from pyaspeller import YandexSpeller
def spellcheck2(text):
    try:
        speller = YandexSpeller()
        changes = {change['word']: change['s'][0] for change in speller.spell(text)}
        for word, suggestion in changes.items():
            text = text.replace(word, suggestion)
        return text
    except:
        return 'error'
```